# Try/Catch blocks the application

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a C# Form Application that talks to an Arduino. 
I want to make sure that the port I'm trying to connect to is the right one. It connects to the right port, but when the port is another one, the application becomes blocked. I checked, and in the try block, port.ReadLine() triggers a TimeoutException. But the Form becomes unresponsive.

```
 private bool isPortToArduino(SerialPort port)
    {
        String response = null;

        port.Write("a");
        try
        {
            response = port.ReadLine();

        }
        catch(TimeoutException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }

        if (response == "y\r")
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It throws the exception before or after the form becomes unresponsive?

Comment: @cubrr: I read that post, and I know that nothing will be received, since it is the wrong port. I tried to use a timeout or thread sleep, but I don't know how to make it work.

BradleyDotNET when i run it with a watch, and set it to port.ReadLine() its value is timeoutexception. But although the code should catch it, it doesnt.